# Animated markers on Mapkit

Tags: ios, mapkit

Is it possible to draw sprites or fluent animated markers over a Mapkit Google map?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Luckily you didn't ask how...

Comment: Thanks for the information. May I ask you how to do it in an optimal way?

Comment: I don't know how MapKit works, haven't used it. But since it's using UIKit and CoreAnimation, I know for sure that you can draw sprites and animations ;-) It can simply be broken down into two problems which you can research independently: How do you do custom markers? And how do you do the kind of animation you have in mind (you didn't tell)? I'm sure you'll find answers to both questions here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was pretty easy to include an animation for `MKAnnotation`.
You just need to add an animated `UIImageView` as a subview inside the `MKAnnotationView` you return for `viewForAnnotation:` method for that particular annotation.

Comment: This is a key point.  Setting the `MKAnnotationView`'s image to an animated `UIImage` with `setImage:` does not work.  (If you use `setImage:` you don't get the animation, just the first frame.)

Answer (score 1):

Try by making custom markers and than add animated UIImageview.